# Merge a dataframe to another dataframe without existing data

Tags: python, pandas

Need to merge a DataFrame with another DataFrame without affecting existing data

df1:

| Name | Subject | mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Ta | 52 |
| b | En |  |
| c | Ma |  |
| d | Ss | 60 |

df2:

| Name | mark |
| --- | --- |
| b | 57 |
| c | 58 |

Expected Output:

| Name | Subject | mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Ta | 52 |
| b | En | 57 |
| c | Ma | 58 |
| d | Ss | 60 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `merge` and `combine_first`:

```
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='outer')
>>> df['mark'] = df.pop('mark_x').combine_first(df.pop('mark_y'))
>>> df
  Name Subject  mark
0    a      Ta  52.0
1    b      En  57.0
2    c      Ma  58.0
3    d      Ss  60.0
>>>
```

Comment: Looks a bit complicated for a simple combine ;) combine first uses index for keys (see my answer)

Comment: @mozway Ah you nailed it... nice one +1

Answer (score 4):

Use `combine_first` after setting Name as index:

```
df1.set_index('Name').combine_first(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
  Name Subject  mark
0    a      Ta  52.0
1    b      En  57.0
2    c      Ma  58.0
3    d      Ss  60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways in which you can achieve this is by using the below steps:

1. Inner join the 2 tables using the `pandas.merge()`command.
2. Create a new column which basically checks if the `marks` column from `df1` is not None, then take that value, else, take `df2` column value.